# Javascript storing information across pages

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I've been trying to save javascript variables across pages with sessionStorage.

As I understand, the syntax is:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('whateverkey', 'whatever value');
```

Is there a way to save a variable inside sessionStorage, or other easy ways to save information across pages

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That code works fine for me. How are you trying to access it? ETA: Oh, session storage won't work over different pages.

Comment: use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`

Comment: Thanks! localStorage worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My value is 'null' when I try to access it from another page.

This is [exactly how `sessionStorage` is designed to work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

> The `sessionStorage` property allows you to access a session Storage object. `sessionStorage` is similar to `Window.localStorage`, the only difference is while data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration set, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. **Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated**, which differs from how session cookies work.

If you want your data to persist across pages on the same origin, use `localStorage` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`sessionStorage` is used to store data for one page/tab, once you close it, you loose the data, and if you open another tab with the same domain, you will have a new instance of `sessionStorage` clean.

What you want, is to use `localStorage`, which is available for all tabs (with the same domain).

> `sessionStorage` maintains a separate storage area for each given origin
>   that's available for the duration of the page session (as long as the
>   browser is open, including page reloads and restores).
>
> `localStorage` does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and
>   reopened. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

Answer (score 0):

You can save strings and integers, you can't save objects. However you can serialize things and save JSON.

`localStorage` is for permanently storing data, while `sessionStorage` is to just temporarily store data until the user closes the web browser.

The syntax you used is correct. You use `setItem` to store and `getItem` to load.

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 'Alice');
localStorage.setItem('marbles', 22);
localStorage.setItem('admin', true);
```

or:

```
var animal = {"type": "cat", "food": "catfood"};
localStorage.setItem('animal', JSON.stringify(animal));
```

then you can get it:

```
var json = localStorage.getItem('animal');
var animal = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: Any special permissions or configurations required to allow using localStorage or sessionStorage in the web browser?

Comment: @tarekahf No. There are no special permissions required on the web browser.